# undefined como primeiro elemento em um loop "for" no JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um array de objetos, ao percorrer esse array com um loop "for" eu recebo um undefined no primeiro elemento ao tentar concatenar esses elementos em uma variável. Qual maneira eu posso usar para resolver esse problema?

```js
var chapterPages = [
    {
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageFile: '1.jpg'
    },
    {
        pageNumber: 2,
        pageFile: '2.jpg'
    },
    {
        pageNumber: 3,
        pageFile: '3.jpg'
    },
    {
        pageNumber: 4,
        pageFile: '4.jpg'
    },
    {
        pageNumber: 5,
        pageFile: '5.jpg'
    }
];

var pagesNavigation;

for (var i = 0; i < chapterPages.length; i++) {
    pagesNavigation += `
    <option value="${i}">${chapterPages[i].pageFile}</option>
    `;
};

console.log(pagesNavigation);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`undefined` não é o primeiro elemento do for, `undefined` é a sua variável `pagesNavigation`. Como você não deu um valor inicial pra ela, o javascript infere `undefined`. Então na primeira iteração do loop, você está fazendo

```
undefined + '<option value="${i}">${chapterPages[i].pageFile}</option>'
```

Como são valores de tipos diferentes, o JS vai transformar o `undefined` armazenado na variável `pagesNavigation` em string e concatenar ele com a tag option, resultando em:

```
'undefined<option value="0">valorQualquer</option>'
```

Para evitar que isso aconteça, atribua um valor inicial a `pagesNavigation`:

```
var pagesNavigation = '';
```

Comment: Blz, vou tentar aqui. Obg